# Do not necessary require(s) matter?

Tags: ruby, require

I want to be able to have one ruby file that can `require` all the common dependencies, so that other files can just have one `require` on this shared file.for example; I have *foo.rb* and *bar.rb* and *allrequires.rb*. I want to have the line `require "allrequires.rb"` in both *foo.rb* and *bar.rb*, but `bar.rb` doesn't need all the requires.

Does it matter if I use `require` in .rb file that do not really require that file? Could it have an impact on performance maybe?

I am currently on `ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]`

## Update

It looks like it is not the best idea to 'share'/use all requires in both .rb files. What would be solution to that?

Right now I can think of using file name in a condition.

Comment: What do you mean by the first sentence? What do you mean by sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach of conditional requiring, the following script gives no error on the JSON parser because it is named require1.rb, in scripts that have no name like require1.rb of script2.rb the gem isn't required

```
require 'json' if "require1.rb, script2.rb"[File.basename(__FILE__)]

p File.basename(__FILE__)

text = '[{ "name" : "car", "status": "good"}, { "name" : "bus", "status": "bad"},{ "name" : "taxi", "status": "soso"},
  {"noname":"", "status" : "worse"}
]' 
data = JSON.parse(text) 

p data.collect { |item| item['name'] }
```

EDIT: here a version that uses an array

```
["require1.rb","script1.rb"].find{|script|require 'json' if script===File.basename(__FILE__)}
```

Comment: I guess what I am looking for is 'conditional requiring'. Could you explain to me the syntax of your if? `if "require1.rb, script2.rb"[File.basename(__FILE__)]`

Comment: Sure, "require1.rb, script2.rb" is the string of scriptnames you want this require to operate on, [] after a string checks if the string inside the brackets is present (a simplified regex), here it is the constant __FILE__ where i get the basename of. So i check if the scriptname is present in the string. You could use an array and use a scan or map function to do the checking, a combination with my other answer here is also possible

Comment: How come the file names are separated by comma? Is this one string or two strings?

Comment: one string, the comma is just a delimiter

Comment: edited my answer to have a version with an array, it's more clear and safer than the stringapproach

Answer (score 3):

There's two main performance penalties:

1. The time taken to do the `require` itself. In Ruby 1.9.1 and Ruby 1.9.2, the time taken to do all the `require`s had worse than linear scalability - if you doubled the number of `require`s, it took you more than twice as long - I think it took you four times as long.
2. The time taken to execute the code in the file being `require`d. If you have code like the following, then executing the code will take a non-trivial amount of time.

```
class MyClass
  MY_CONSTANT = File.read("data.txt")
end
```

Comment: I don't understand #2. Why would it take longer?

Comment: @Radek I've rephrased the first sentence of #2 - does it make sense now?

Comment: I have not so deep ruby/programming knowledge so I cannot grasp why it would take longer to execute code in one (particular) file longer. Because the engine has to search all requires for the right code?

Comment: I updated my question... Could you suggest anu solution to my situation?

Comment: @Radek "I have not so deep ruby/programming knowledge so I cannot grasp why it would take longer to execute code in one (particular) file longer. Because the engine has to search all requires for the right code?" - are you referring to #1 or #2?

Comment: I refer to #2. It might be my English too :-) What does "non-trivial amount of time" mean?

Comment: @Radek Did you try looking up what "non-trivial amount" means?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11286/discussion-between-radek-and-andrew-grimm)

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else reading this: I've given up for now.

Comment: So are these performance penalties 'only' about load time of `require`s after that there is no disadvantages?

Comment: @Radek Once you've done all the requiring, there's no almost always no disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there will be a speedpanalty, you can benchmark how mutch to consider if it realy matters.
With multiple require's i put hem in my code like this so that it doens't take much screenspace.

```
['green_shoes','Hpricot'].each(&method(:require))
```

You could also do a conditional require, but that would be ugly having all around your code

```
begin
  data = JSON.parse(text)
rescue
  require 'json_pure' 
  data = JSON.parse(text)
end
```

So in short, give each rb its own require's

Answer (score 0):

My final solution is (in case someone finds it useful):

requires.rb is called from web.rb or testweb.rb, rufus.rb or testrufus.rb

```
called_from=caller[0].split(":")[0]


puts "loading web 'requires' for file: #{called_from} ..." if (["web"].any?{|s| called_from[s]})
puts "loading web 'requires' for file: #{called_from} ..." if (["rufus"].any?{|s| called_from[s]})
puts "loading web 'requires' for file: #{called_from} ..." if (["settings"].any?{|s| called_from[s]})

require 'rubygems'

require 'socket'        if (["web","settings"].any?{|s| called_from[s]})
require 'ruby-growl'    if (["web","settings","rufus"].any?{|s| called_from[s]})
require 'sinatra'       if (["web"].any?{|s| called_from[s]})
```

Thank you @Andrew for the explanation and @peter for the hint how to solve this.